# Jquery target div inside clicked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a drop down menu using css `:hover` which works great on desktops and android, but breaks on iPad. Because of this I am swapping `:hover` for jquery.

The below does just what I need, almost.

```
var down = false;
$("li").click(function() {
    if (down == false) {
        $(".dropdown").css("height", "150px");
        down = true;
    } else if (down == true) {
        $(".dropdown").css("height", "0px");
        down = false;
    }
});
```

Basically I have a div container named `.dropdown` in each `li`. Can I target the `.dropdown` when its parent `li` is clicked?
At the moment all `.dropdowns` open up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the current `this` reference in the selector, like:

```
$("li").click(function(){
  if (down == false) {
    $(".dropdown",this).css("height", "150px");
    down = true;
  } 
  else if(down == true) {
    $(".dropdown",this).css("height", "0px");
    down = false;
  }
});
```

The `this` as a second element in the `$(...)` makes sure that only child-elements of `this` will be found.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `$(".dropdown")` with `$(".dropdown", this)` to target specific child elements for the `li` that was clicked, which is represented by `this`.